# Is it ok to use Wait to catch Exceptions in ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, task-parallel-library

I've just upgraded my main application from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5 and I'm trying to make use of the more advanced language features that C# 5.0 has to offer.

I'm currently looking at re-writing some old asynchronous code routines which used "MethodInvoker"/"AsyncCallback" (to keep the UI fluid) with **Tasks**.

Here's the pattern the old code follows...

```
void RefreshScreen()
{
  // code to prepare UI for updating
  ...
  MethodInvoker del = new MethodInvoker(LoadData);
  del.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(LoadData_Callback), null);
}

void LoadData()
{
  // perform data calculations
}

void LoadData_Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  AsyncResult res = (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)ar;
  MethodInvoker del = (MethodInvoker)res.AsyncDelegate;
  try
  {
    del.EndInvoke(ar);  // <- throw exception if one occurred during async operation
  }
  catch (Exception E)
  {
    // handle exception
  }

  // Update the UI: if (this.InvokeRequired) {...}
}
```

OK - so here's the **Task-based** equivalent I have so far :-

```
void RefreshScreen()
{
  // code to prepare UI for updating
  ...
  Task.Run(() => LoadData()).ContinueWith((t) => LoadData_Callback(t));
}

void LoadData()
{
  // perform data calculations
}

void LoadData_Callback(Task t)
{
  try
  {
    t.Wait(); // <- throw exception if one occurred during async operation
  }
  catch (Exception E)
  {
    // handle exception
  }

  // Update the UI: if (this.InvokeRequired) {...}
}
```

So here's my question... I've read lots of articles and resources about Exception Handling with Tasks, and a number of them discuss things like checking "**task.IsCompleted**" and/or "**task.Status**", plus branching into multiple **ContinueWiths** using **[TaskContinuationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, so is it acceptable practice to simply call "**task.Wait()**" inside a ContinueWith method, to catch an Exception there (as per the above code) or is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks!

**UPDATE and ANSWER**

In the interests of clarification, I should have explained that the original code is used in a WinForms application, and the goal was to keep the UI responsive during long DB operations (or any other long process), by running them asynchronously on a different thread.

Silas and Servy pointed out that since switching to C# 5.0, I should use **async**/**await**, so this is the code I've chosen to use which is analogous to the above examples...

```
async Task RefreshScreen()
{
  // code to prepare UI for updating
  ...
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() => LoadData());
  }
  catch (Exception E)
  {
    // handle exception
  }
  // Update the UI: WITHOUT the need to check "this.InvokeRequired"
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}

Task LoadData()
{
  // perform data calculations
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

There are at least two benefits this code has over the "**MethodInvoker**" or "**Task**" methods :-
(1) It's much clearer
(2) Ater returning from **await**, the subsequent code is on the UI thread, so there's no need to faff around with "*if (this.InvokeRequired) {...}*" ([see Stephen Cleary's blog for more information on this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)).

What about the original question? *Is it ok to use Wait to catch Exceptions in ContinueWith?*

I guess it's a moot point since **async**/**await** is obviously the way to go, however after further research, the answer is YES it's ok to do that!

Comment: Why aren't you awaiting the task if you're using the C# 5.0 features.  `await` is like *the* C# 5.0 feature.

Comment: That's probably a good question... I'm working my way through *O'Reilly's C# 6.0 in a Nutshell* and haven't got as far as async/await yet, but I got "itchy" and wanted to dive in to start using what I'd learned about **Tasks**! That said - I've just looked at that topic and can't quite understand how to use async/await in an analogous way to the above. :-/

Answer (score 5):

You can replace all of that stuff with this:

```
public async Task LoadData()
{
  // do something DB intensive
}

public async Task HandleLoadExceptions()
{  
    try
    {
        await LoadData();
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Silas, although wouldn't the call to **await LoadData();** be synchronous in that scenario?

Comment: @Hedley No, it would not be, assuming `LoadData` is implemented correctly.

Comment: Forgive me sorry - how could that method be implemented "correctly" to make it asynchronous? Don't you have to use Task.Run(...) to actually start the new thread?

Comment: Correctly means that all long-running work is implemented `async` all the way down. Typically involves using async libraries/methods for the actual work.

Comment: @SilasReinagel That's also wrong.  `async` simply allows for the use of the `await` keyword in the body of the method.  It does not force the method the be asynchronous, rather it simply allowed for a particular keyword (`await`) to be used in *potentially* making it asynchronous.  A synchronous method can be marked `async` (it'd be a super evil thing to do, but you can do it).

Comment: @Hedley You don't *have* to use `Task.Run` to do work in another thread, but it is one way to do it.  Since your work isn't CPU bound work though, you have no need for another thread, you just need to send of your network request and do your stuff when it gets back.  You don't need a thread for that.  Scheduling a thread pool thread just to have it sit there doing nothing for you is just wasting system resources.

Comment: @Servy You are correct. My explanation didn't involve enough context. I deleted that segment.

Comment: I just tried testing this in a WinForms app. If I call **"await LoadData();"** it blocks the UI thread (hence is running synchronously) whereas if I call **"await Task.Run(() => LoadData());"** it doesn't block the UI thread, hence it must be asynchronous. If the purpose of this is to keep the UI responsive, is this a good approach?

Comment: @Hedley what they are trying to tell you is that the first one should become `await LoadDataAsync();`

Comment: @Hedley That means that your current LoadData internal implementation is synchronous. Using `Task.Run` to dispatch it effectively solves the problem. A better long term solution is to use an async DB library

Comment: @SilasReinagel That makes sense - thanks. Unfortunately it's an old file-based DB which is not asynchronous, so I think that's helped me to answer the question :-)

Comment: @Hedley Accessing the DB synchronously vs asynchronously has nothing to do with the database itself, it it purely based on the code you use to connect to it.  The underlying DB operations will *always* be asynchronous; it's inherent in the nature of the operation.

Comment: @Servy I understand that writing data to a disk is asynchronous from CPU processing, but I presumed when Silas said about using an "async DB library", he meant one that supported asynchronous calls, for example SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery / SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery? Given that I don't have that option and the only calls I can make to the DB layer are synchronous, then the only way I can see to keep the UI responsive while a DB operation is being carried out is to make my code asynchronous. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Hedley The code that you use to query your DB from your application is *very* different from the actual DB itself.  You could be using a DB that's 50 years old, much older than me, but querying it using tools that are only a few years old.  Additionally, it's not like people only started writing software to query a DB asynchronously recently; most any decent query provider has had asynchronous options for their entire lifetime.  If you have a bad query provider that doesn't expose any asynchronous operations, then that is unfortunate, yes, and they've forced you to have to work around that.

Comment: `the only way I can see to keep the UI responsive while a DB operation is being carried out is to make my code asynchronous. Am I wrong?`  No, that's not wrong.  What's wrong is thinking that you need a second thread to make the operation asynchronous.  You don't need any additional threads to make the operation asynchronous.

Comment: There are `async` versions to connect to the DB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonqueryasync.aspx

Comment: @Servy OK - so I understand what you're saying: that you can program asynchronously on one thread and the Tasks are interleaved on that thread... however in WinForms development, when the goal is to keep the UI responsive, there doesn't seem to be much point implementing asynchronous code and then running it all on the UI thread. The end result would still be an unresponsive UI during long operations. I'm going to update the original post with better clarification that the goal was really to keep the UI responsive in a WinForms app. Many thanks for you help!

Comment: @Hedley DB operations *don't require the work of any thread*.  You don't need to have a thread, whether it's the UI thread or any other thread, just sitting there doing nothing while the DB does work.   It's like you saying that you're expecting a letter, and you're only choices are to sit in front of your mailbox all day waiting for the letter, or since you have other stuff you want to do, to hire a guy to just sit there all day waiting by your mailbox to give you the letter.  You just don't need to do that.  You don't need some person to sit there doing nothing all day to get your mail.

Comment: @Servy I think you win StackOverflow. That metaphor is amazing!

Comment: As mentioned, I understand that pure DB or I/O operations do not require a separate thread. Please understand that the original question was simplified for the sake of clarity, but the real word situation (as always) is more complex. I'm working on a legacy application with a "database-layer". The DB layer mixes data retrieval and processing. Some calls just retrieve a DataSet from the DB. Other's do a lot of work internally, retrieving multiple datasets, iterating though, performing calculations and building a resulting dataset. Surely the best solution in this scenario is to use a thread?